# mod_pagespeed with SSL: from // to https://

Tags: apache, mod-pagespeed

Apache 2.2.15 on RHELS 6.1

Using mod_pagespeed on a server behind https (implemented by the network's Reverse Proxy).

All html urls are written as "//server.example.com/path/to/file.css" (so, without the protocol specified).

Problem : using the default configuration, pagespeed rewrites the urls as "http://server.example.com/path/to/file.css"

I'm trying to figure out how to have it rewrite the urls as https (or leave it unspecified as //).

After reading the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/https_support#map_the_origin), I tried using ModPagespeedMapOriginDomain like this

```
ModPagespeedMapOriginDomain http://localhost https://server.example.com
```

Also tried

```
ModPagespeedMapOriginDomain http://localhost //server.example.com
ModPagespeedMapOriginDomain localhost server.example.com
```

... To  no avail. Urls keep being rewritten with "http://".

Question: how can I have pagespeed use https instead of http in its urls?

[Full pagespeed config here, if needed](http://pastebin.com/UikKMhW6)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out mod_pagespeed does not work with "protocol-relative" urls.

Still, the issue is bypassed if you enable [trim_urls](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-trim-urls)

```
ModPagespeedEnableFilters trim_urls
```

Be mindful of the potential risks (depending on your javascript codebase, ajax calls could break or produce unexpected html).

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to your configuration might work:

```
ModPagespeedRespectXForwardedProto on
```

That works, if your reverse proxy forwards the X-Forwarded-Proto header in its requests.
That request header tells PageSpeed what the original protocol was that was used for the request at the loadbalancer, and thereby hands it all it needs to know to correctly rewrite urls.